# How can I login to custom authentication url in Spring Webflux Security?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I want to login to Spring Webflux Security through the changed authentication URL(/api/authenticate). So I made this code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class WebFluxSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("user")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();

        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user, admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .requiresAuthenticationMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/api/authenticate"))
                .authenticationSuccessHandler((webFilterExchange, authentication) -> {
                    webFilterExchange.getExchange().getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
                    return Mono.empty();
                })
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

And then, I tried to login with user/user and admin/admin to localhost:8080/api/authenticate but it gives me response status code 302 and login?error.

How can I login with user/user and admin/admin to custom url localhost:8080/api/authenticate?

Comment: Why havnt you enabled debug logs and read the logs?

Comment: I read the debug log that 'Checking match of request : '/api/authenticate'; against '/api/authenticate'', 'matched' and 'Authentication failed: Invalid Credentials'

Comment: well there is your problem. invalid credentials